# Static and dynamic drawing/painting in titanium

Tags: javascript, drawing, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-modules

I am working on an application (for both iOS and Android) in which I need to allow the user to select photo from gallery and encircle some item by drawing on the image. As soon as the user finishes drawing he is prompted to name the item in pop up. After naming the item is added into items table and an arrow automatically connects the circle and item. Both photos and items have separate tables.

I used Ti.Paint for drawing but it only supports dynamic(manual) drawing through finger. This module have not any methods to draw shapes like line,circle etc programatically. Also it doesn't provide touch events so I can't detect when the user stopped drawing. Then I used Ti.Canvas but it only supports static drawing i.e. user can't draw with finger dynamically and also it only supports iOS. I tried a lot in 2 days with touch events to do this to no avail. Here's my code for drawing with touch using Ti.Canvas:

```
      canvas.addEventListener('touchstart',function(e) {
          canvas.begin();
          canvas.beginPath();
          canvas.moveTo(e.x,e.y);
      })

      canvas.addEventListener('touchmove',function(e) {
          canvas.lineTo(e.x,e.y);
          canvas.stroke();
      })

      canvas.addEventListener('touchend',function(e) {
          canvas.commit();
      })
```

But unluckily this isn't working. Can somebody tell how can I solve this problem. Is there some module or libraries exist which support both static(programmatic) and manual(through touch) drawing. I'll be very grateful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I know I had an example of touchend being used.  In this example code, which may not operate the same on both IOS and Android, has an example of touchend.
http://developer.appcelerator.com/blog/2010/05/building-an-advanced-transaction-ui-with-titanium.html

The source code to the Ti.Paint module is available and you could add the functionality that you want to it.
https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/paint

If you didn't want to go down that road, there is a canvas module that allows you to create lines, though I haven't tested it.  This appears to be IOS specific.
https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_modules/tree/master/canvas/mobile/ios

For Android, it looks like there is a module.
https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/apps/5941?494596078

So you have some options out there to look into.

Comment: Which module is more suitable for following...i want to make control with three squares connected with lines and touch event can change the position and shape, for both iOS/Android. its not drawing control where user draws..it just changes the shape.